# How to set 'timeout' using FuelSDK during SOAP Call

Tags: soap-api, fuel-sdk, timeout

I want to know that how can we set `timeout` for requests that use SOAP.

In `REST`, when we send the request at that time we set timeout: `request.get(timeout=150)`.

But is there any way in the `SOAP` Call (particularly using FuelSDK)?

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck on that one too. After you define your client authentication like this:

```
    myClient = FuelSDK.ET_Client(arg1, arg2,...)
```

You can set the option of timeout in seconds:

```
    myClient.soap_client.set_options(timeout=150)
```

The default value for timeout is 90.